# Indigo Installation, Environment setup

Tags: ros, installation, bashrc, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

BH

**Hello,
I have tried ,a couple of times, to install the indigo desktop full package library but when I reached to the Environment setup section and typed the source ~/.bashrc command, the response was that there is no setup.bash file. I searched the installation directories and saw that indeed no such file exists. It seems as if the installation completed without any failure, as I haven't got any errors and the packages installed altogether weigh 135MB.

Could someone suggest what to do? ****

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206940/indigo-installation,-environment-setup/) by [Haz88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22113/haz88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file */opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash* is part of the package **ros-indigo-catkin**, make sure it is installed. That package is one of the most basic ones in ros, so I suppose something went wrong during installation and I advice you to purge ros (like mentioned in the answer before) and re-install ros.

---

Originally posted by [georg l](https://answers.ros.org/users/22092/georg-l/) with karma: 186 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0